# using multiple mysql query loop inside each other

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have a big trouble using multiple queries inside each other. and i searched for it but could not find what i needed!
so this is my problem. plz help me.

i have a table named "cat" and i get the titles by mysql and it's ok. i have an other table named works that has a field named "Cat_ID" this is the field that connect's the data of both tables. works table has another field named "Years" and it's the year of the production of artwork.

cat >> { ID , Title , ... }
works >> { ID , Title , URL , Year , Cat_ID , ... }

i need to categorize the gallery of works by year, so i made a code like this:

```
<?php
$result = q("cat");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="artwork.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['Title']; ?></a></h2>
    <span>
    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM works WHERE Cat=".$row['Cat_ID'];
      $yresult = mysql_query($sql);
      while ($yrow = mysql_fetch_row($yresult)) 
      {
        //and print it as anchor here but it wont get into loop at all!                         
      }                         
    ?>
    </span>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

the q() is a function that just connects to DB and run the query. this line works pretty well.
but the it wont enter to the inner while at all! i checked and saw that the $yrow is totally empty(by EMPTY() of php)!
what can i do about it? it seems that mysql can not execute the second query at all! the solution must be in two ways i think.
1. make mysql to execute the second query.
2. change the first query in the way that get's the years distinctly and read them by mysql_fetch_array and put the years as anchor via for each.

plz help me.

Comment: This would be a lot more efficient if you could do a join on your two SQL queries

Comment: Are you sure your queries are correct and working? What does `mysql_error` show?

Comment: sql shows no err it just simply returns nothing at all!

Comment: Perhaps you'd car to show us the SQL query for `q("cat");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having multiple loops, use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT works.Year FROM cat INNER JOIN works ON (cat.ID = works.Cat_ID)
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but the structure of my tables are like this:
cat >> { ID , Title , ... }  and the works table is like this 
works >> { ID , Title , URL , Year , Cat_ID , ... }

i need an array like this for plz:

Cat { Title , .... , Years{ 2005,2009,2010,...} }